# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable in TensorFlow when building a GAN

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to build a GAN for a university assignment. My code is very similar to the intro example in [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan?hl=en) from TF's website.

Below are what I think the relevant parts of the code (can provide more details if needed eg. how the discriminator model is built). The line that gives me the error is:

```
generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generador.trainable_variables))
```

It might be related with the layers of my generator since it is almost the only difference with TF's example code..

```
def create_generator(max_len, vocab_size):
  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, output_dim=64, input_length=max_len))  
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=1024, activation='tanh'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1024, activation='sigmoid'))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=MAX_LEN, activation=None))

  return model

generator = create_generator(MAX_LEN, VOCABULARY_SIZE)

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
  noise = (tf.random.uniform([BATCH_SIZE, LATENT_DIM], minval=0, maxval = VOCABULARY_SIZE))

  with tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape, tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape:

    # Generator loss    
    fake_revs = generator(noise)
    pred_class_fake_revs = discriminator(fake_revs)
    gen_loss, gen_acc = generator_loss_and_accuracy(pred_class_fake_revs)

    # Disc loss
    real_revs = reviews_tok_padded[np.random.randint(0, len(reviews_tok_padded),BATCH_SIZE)]
    pred_class_real_revs = discriminator(real_revs) 
    disc_loss, disc_acc = discriminator_loss_and_accuracy(pred_class_real_revs, pred_class_fake_revs)

    gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)    
    disc_grad = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
    disc_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(disc_grad, discriminator.trainable_variables))
```

The exact error I get is:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['embedding_22/embeddings:0', 'lstm_22/lstm_cell_30/kernel:0', 'lstm_22/lstm_cell_30/recurrent_kernel:0', 'lstm_22/lstm_cell_30/bias:0', 'dense_44/kernel:0', 'dense_44/bias:0', 'dense_45/kernel:0', 'dense_45/bias:0'].
```

Edit: after some further investigation it is clear that the issue is that the tape does not compute the gradient, so the variable `gradients_of_generator` equals none for all `generator.trainable_variables`. However, I don't know why this happens.

Comment: During the forward pass, you are using different gradient tape (disc_tape_real, disc_tape_fake), but you are trying to compute the gradients of discriminator from a different tape altogether (gen_tape or disc_tape).........

gen_tap has no track of the graph

Comment: You are right that's an issue. However that was an error from copying the code and simplifying a bit it to make this post. I've just fixed it and still get the same issue.

Comment: I have reproduced your code in colab, I am getting no error, and the gradients are computing fine. Can you share your code with the error in colab? because I don't see any error in this

Comment: Hi. I just found what was causing the issue. See answer below. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally found what was causing the issue. It is related with the layers in the discriminator model, which is not even included in the code chunk above as I thought that was not the problem (because when I tested the discriminator as a standalone model, it worked). Here is how it is defined:

```
    def crear_discriminador():
      model = tf.keras.Sequential()    
      model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=VOCABULARY_SIZE, output_dim=64, input_length=MAX_LEN))
      model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=64, activation='tanh')))
      model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
      model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    
    return model
```

The issue is that the Embedding layer is not differentiable, so when combining the generator and the discriminator, the embedding layer in the discriminator was preventing the gradient from being calculated for the layers in the generator.

Comment: The problem now is that not being able to use RNN based layers (since they need embedding) means that the GAN performs much worse for generating text, which is what I am trying to do.. So any suggestion on how to tackle this are welcome

Comment: embedding layer is trainable IMO but i guess you are doing argmax to choose the right indexes from the generator before passing it to discriminator which does not provide gradients.